# Executing Python Program Within Another Python Program

Tags: python, execute

Recently I have created a python program "program1" which makes changes to a text file and then prints the changes to a new text file.

Now, I have created a program "program2" which checks a directory for any files ending with a number. This program then executes the previous "program1" onto the specified files.

However, the problem I'm having is that "program1" only points to a specified file to make changes. I want "program2" to run "program1" onto different files.

For example, here is "program 1"'s code.

```
def my_main(ifile_name, ofile_name):




ifile_name = open(ifile_name, 'r')
lines = ifile_name.readlines()

ofile_name = open(ofile_name, "w")
start = 0
end = len(lines) - 1
while start < end:
    ofile_name.write(lines[start])
    ofile_name.write(lines[end])
    start += 1
    end -= 1
if start == end:
    ofile_name.write(lines[start])
ifile_name.close()
ofile_name.close()
```

This program opens "ifile_name" which is a specified text file, then prints the changes to "ofile_name" which is another specified text file. I want "program 2" to execute "program 1" on the files that I will specify on "program 2".

So far, here is the attempt I have made. I am trying to get "program2" to open "program1" and edit the value for "ofile_name" to the value that the user will specify in "program2". Is this possible? Or are there better ways of achieving this? 
Thank you.

Code is as follows:

```
import os
import re
import program1

def my_main():

    directoryname = raw_input("Please provide path to directory")
    for filenames in os.listdir(directoryname):
        if re.match(r'w*\d+.txt', filenames):
            with open(program1, 'r')as file:
                for ofile_name in file:
                    ofile_name = filenames
                    execfile(ex01)
```

Comment: Why don't you import it and call the function?

Comment: I agree with @Daniel. Change `my_main` to a more specific name, `modify_file` for example, then add `from program1 import modify_file`.

Comment: Thanks guys I will give it a try now :)

Comment: you can directly run the program2 from program1 using subprocess